# callback function executing twice nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi guys I am having another problem , while user signs up i am getting following error

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
at d:\Nodejs\New folder\controllers\user_op.js:71:13
at Query.Model.$wrapCallback (d:\Nodejs\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3361:16)
at d:\Nodejs\New folder\node_modules\kareem\index.js:259:21
at d:\Nodejs\New folder\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

after debug, i found that registervalidate function executing twice is runnning twice..and validating details twice...At first execution it sends response...at 2nd execution it doesnt find callback as a function

Sign-Up

```js
exports.signUp = function(req, res) {
    query = req.body;
    var userData = [];
    for (var key in query) {
        userData.push(query[key]);
    }
    user.registerValidate(query, function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            bcrypt.hash(query.pword, null, null, function(err, hash) {
                query.pword = hash;
                user.createUser(query, function(bool2) {
                    if (bool2) {
                        res.send("User created");
                    } else {
                        res.send("Problem Occured");
                    }
                });

            });

        } else {
            res.send("USER IS NOT VALID");
        }
    });

}
```

it uses this for validation and it is running twice..

```js
exports.registerValidate = function(data, callback) {


    // this.loginValidate(userData[0], function(data) {
    //     if (data != null) {
    //         isValid = false;
    //     } else
    //     if (!util.validateMobile(userData[2])) {
    //         isValid = false;
    //     } else
    //     if (!util.validateEmail(userData[1])) {
    //         isValid = false;
    //     }
    //     callback(isValid);

    // });
    var User = require("../Models/UserSchema").model('User');
    User.findOne({
        uname: data.uname
    }, function(err, query) {
        var isValid = true;
        if (err) throw console.log(err);
        if (query != null) {
            isValid = false;
            callback(isValid);
        } else
        if (!util.validateMobile(data.mobile_no)) {
            isValid = false;
            callback(isValid);
            return;
        } else
        if (!util.validateEmail(data.email)) {
            isValid = false;
            callback(isValid);
            return;
        } else {
            callback(isValid);
            return;
        }

    });

}
```

At first i thought loginValidate is causing problem...so i commented it out..
pls tell be whats the problem

Comment: Can you check for occurrences of registerValidate in your source code and also put a break point at the function start and check for the stack trace.

Comment: You need to refresh your understanding of [how nodejs style callbacks work](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/). And that code has some really confusing syntax. Stick to scoped `if` blocks with `{}`.

Comment: `return callback(query != null && util.validateMobile() && util.validateEmail())`